# Locked in Cyrillic boot

Tags: boot

I can not boot Ubuntu 18.04 and need  manually  do fsck /dev/sda3.
However, once pressed f10 at root my typing alphabet is  changed to Cyrillic.
I do not know what happended.
So I am basically stuck between the need to type fsck command and the fact that I type in Cyrillic.
Is there way to change it to english alphabet?
thanks

Comment: Have you tried to press Alt+Shift for switching keyboard layout?

Comment: yes, tried, no change

Comment: To fix the fsck problem you can boot from any Ubuntu live/installation media and then check the filesystem from it.

Comment: No can do, I can not access hard disk from usb boot.  Says you do not have r/w access - denied. Tried also mount  in disk, then fsck, still no access